# android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException:Index -1 requested, with a size of 0

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to use a cursor to return the most recently added entry into a database. I get the error in the title when I send the following code:

```
    SQLiteDatabase db =getReadableDatabase();
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM "+SPORTS_TABLE_NAME+" ORDER BY Sport_id DESC LIMIT 1;";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
    db.close();
    return cursor.getInt(0);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You forgot to move to the first record. You are now pointed before the first one (therefore, the index is still -1). Also, it seems that your query is not returning any record at all (record count = 0)

Comment: he aslo close the db before getting value from cursor

Comment: Ok cool so I chaged the code a little bit so that my db is still open when i store the info and the error has changed, it now says -1 requested with a size of 1..
How do i move to the first record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code have to be like the following:

```
int id = 0;
SQLiteDatabase db =getReadableDatabase();
String sql = "SELECT * FROM "+SPORTS_TABLE_NAME+" ORDER BY Sport_id DESC LIMIT 1";
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    id = cursor.getInt(0);
}
if(cursor != null)
    db.close();
return id;
```